# External Disc (Western Digital Ultra for Mac 5TB) disconnecting it self, but still shown in finder. Have to restart or reconnect

Tags: imac, external-disk

I wouldn't write here, if I wouldn't try all I could until now. My new 5TB is randomly disconnecting and I'm unable to access the data or use the alias on it. Although it is still shown in finder, but all the folders are missing. On the other hand, it shows the used space on disk. After a restart or ejecting and reconnecting the drive, the folders will be back again....and after few hours or days disappear again.  I just both the iMac 3 weeks ago and it is running the Mac OS Monterey 12.3.1
I have tried to reinstall the whole operating system, run it in safe mode, change the sleep configuration in terminal, off course try a different port and USB-C cable.I also erased the whole disc and have formated it as Journaled (which it was before as well)
The issue doesn't appear on my wife's Mac running on Catalina, neither I have this problem with my other WD 3TB drive on my iMac. It seems like all the hardware is perfectly working. Just not together:-( I'm quite running out of ideas...watched pretty all videos and red all articles I could find, but nothing helped. Does anybody have a suggestion?
When trying to open photos app which is connected to mentioned drive I get the -36 error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remember the first rule of troubleshooting, "isolate and identify."

So you simplify troubleshooting by ensuring that only the HD is connected to the Mac (other than keyboard/mouse). If it is still disconnecting, then you further isolate the problem by trying a different data cable, and then a different power cable if at all possible.

If it is still disconnecting, you further isolate it to a computer issue. Can you plug it into another Mac? Does it still happen?

If not, there is an issue with your Mac. If it still happens it is most probably a problem with the drive, or the case that provides the USB and power to the drive inside of it.

Depending on your comfort level and the status of your drive's warranty you can either take the bare drive out of the case and try it in another case, or return it for warranty replacement.

If there is valuable data on the drive, data recovery is sometimes possible, though potentially expensive. There are a number of companies that specialize in recovering data from failed drives, easily found by internet search.